# Rendered result and actual animation is different

Tags: rendering

I rendered a video but the result I got is a bit different from what I made.
I put armateurs in my object and it's supposed to walk in the animation (it's walking properly when I play in layout) but in the video I got, the object is just moving from A to B and doesn't do any walking move.
Also, camera angle got a little different result from what I set in blender.[image]

[image]

Comment: At least I can see that Armature is disabled on render.

Comment: As @Crantisz says, the armature is disabled in render, that's the reason why there is no walking animation. For the camera angle it's hard to tell since we cannot see the camera settings.